# React testing: class component with props with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a class component with props with Enzyme but get the following error:

```
<FormUserDetails /> rendering › FormUserDetails: renders correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'formErrors' of undefined

      23 |               <input
      24 |                 id="input-form-name"
    > 25 |                 className={values.formErrors.name.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
```

I think the problem might be with passing props to my tests: how can I tell Enzyme to look for values?

I am new to Enzyme, so I wonder what I am missing. Following are the relevant code:

Here is the component I am testing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class FormUserDetails extends Component {

  // Go to the next page on submit
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.nextStep()
  }

  render() {
    const {values, handleChange, nextStep } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
        <div className='page-detail'>
          <h3 className="alignleft">User Details</h3>
          <p className="aligncenter">Privacy</p>
          <p className="alignright">Done</p>
        </div>
          <form className="form">
            <div className="name">
              <input
                id="input-form-name"
                className={values.formErrors.name.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                placeholder="Name *"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                noValidate
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {values.formErrors.name.length > 0 && (
                <span className="errorMessage">{values.formErrors.name}</span>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="role">
              <input
                id="input-form-role"
                placeholder="Role"
                type="text"
                name="role"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="email">
              <input
                id="input-form-email"
                className={values.formErrors.email.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                placeholder="Email *"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {values.formErrors.email.length > 0 && (
                <span className="errorMessage">{values.formErrors.email}</span>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="password">
              <input
                id="input-form-password"
                className={values.formErrors.password.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                placeholder="Password *"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {values.formErrors.password.length > 0 && (
                <span className="errorMessage">{values.formErrors.password}</span>
              )}
            </div>
          </form>
          <button id='btn-next' onClick={nextStep}>Next</button>
          <br/>
          <small><i>Fields marked with * are required</i></small>
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
  }
}


export default FormUserDetails
```

And here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import FormUserDetails from '../components/FormUserDetails';



describe('<ForUserDetails /> rendering', () => {
    it('ForUserDetails: renders correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(
            <FormUserDetails 
                values={{formErrors: { name: '', email: '', password: ''}}} 
                handleChange={() => {}} 
                nextStep={() => {}} 
            />).toJSON() 

        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are expecting inside component here:

```
const {values, handleChange, nextStep } = this.props
```

that the prop `values` will be passed but inside your test you don't do this.

So you have to pass props to your components inside your tests (in your example should be: `const tree = renderer.create(<FormUserDetails values={ formErrors: { name: '', email: '', password: '' } } handleChange={() => {}} nextStep={() => {}} />).toJSON()`);

Comment: Hi pako thanks, really helps. I keep having the same error, is it because we need to declare a props function with the actual values (`formErrors.name`) on top of the test?

Comment: You have to provide full `formErrors` object like this: `values={ formErrors: { name: '', email: '', password: '' } }` because you are expecting inside component that this object will have those keys.

Comment: Yes, it's what I did then but still doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: I made it works thanks: I had to add all the values from the upper component, not only `formErrors`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MaJa: great, so please mark my answer as correct ;) (vote up)